# How to convert query with many joins and inner select to Laravel ORM

Tags: laravel, orm, laravel-query-builder

Hi guys please help solve this problem.
Need to convert this query to Laravel ORM.

```
$user = Auth::user();
$datas = DB::select('select * from kvits k
                left join (select o.kvit_id, sum(o.amount * o.price) as sum from operations o
                group by o.kvit_id) s on k.id = s.kvit_id
                left join users u on k.user_id = u.id
                left join users h on k.hamkor_id = h.id
                left join stores s2 on k.store_id = s2.id
                where k.user_id = ' $user->id  ');
```

Main problem is how to convert this query to Larave ORM.
Basically this part

```
left join (select o.kvit_id, sum(o.amount * o.price) as sum from operations o
            group by o.kvit_id) s on k.id = s.kvit_id
```

Second problem is:
Why Laravel getting the last join id in the column without taking all the ids (e.g. k.id, ****, u.id, ***, s.id on this query). And does not display data from all other joined columns.
How to get them.

[image: Here is dd($datas) photo]

I want to get data all joined tables also, like `k.id, k.date, ... u.id, u.name, .... s.id, s.name, s.notes` .  Like belowed table.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

First, `Why Laravel getting the last join id in the column without taking all the ids (e.g. k.id, ****, u.id, ***, s.id on this query).`, Laravel uses PDO to fetch data from the database, and PDO fetches the data by the column name and not by the `table_name.column_name` index.

Basically what you have to do is create your Model (the model that will contain all this data together) like that **(it is a model example)**:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class MyUserModel extends Model {
    public function addresses() {
         // query all addresses of this user and returns it
    }

    public function phone () {
         // query User's phone from database and returns it
    }

    // ...
}
```

and then when you want to use some value, for example, you want to get the User's phone ID, you just use `$user->phone->id` and Laravel will run the `phone()` method from `MyUserModel` class. To learn more about go to [Laravel Eloquent Relationships Queries Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relations)

if you want to always load these data together whenever a query with this model is made, you can use the `protected $with` model variable to can fetch all data. [see more on Laravel Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading-by-default).

CAUTION: If you want to customize the method query from outside the method you must call the method as a Function, for example `$user->phone()->where('active', 1)`, and not as a Dynamic Property like `$user->phone->where('active', 1)`.

Comment: thanks for your answer to help me.
Main question is how to convert this query to laravel ORM.

Comment: you can use SQL alias instead

Comment: ```left join users u``` here is ```u``` is a SQL alias

Comment: no man, you need to use SQL alias on selected names, like `SELECT u.id as user_id, k.id as kvits_id`, etc.